# ThreadedHTTPServer is opening threads before any request arrives

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, httpserver

I have a python script with a simple ThreadedHTTPServer. I am running it on a linux server and once I start the script, before any request arrives, I see many threads (~40). 
How can I set a maximum on the number of threads the server starts with?
How can I set a maximum on the number of threads the server will use while requests arrive?

```
class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
            pass

def start_server():
            server = ThreadedHTTPServer((HOST, PORT), handler.Handler)
            server_thread = threading.Thread(name='server', target=server.serve_forever)
            server_thread.setDaemon(True)
            server_thread.start()
            server_thread.join()
            server.shutdown()
            server.server_close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        start_server()
```

Comment: You could use `threading.activeCount()` to count your threads

Comment: that would give me more information :) but I still want to know where does the magical number of threads comes from..

Comment: I dont know , mabe it has to do with `handler.Handler` ? You could print `threading.current_thread()` to debug it

Comment: I did as you suggested and it seems the server opens a new thread for each request and doesn't close the thread once the response is sent